# Location of CRX in chrome after installation?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im doing a project that involves browser extension. In firefox i do know the location of where the extensions will be after you download them (under your profile folder) and I was wondering where does Chrome hides the crx after you install them? Especially in mac.

I'm doing this coz i find it easier to build extension by look how other people tackles the problem especially XPCOM and now bumping into some issue with chrome extensions.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

CRX files are basically ZIP files. After you install an extension, all the files are in a folder named according to the extension ID. To get the extension ID, go to `chrome://extensions/` and make sure Developer mode is checked.

Installed Chrome extension directories:

### Mac

```
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions
```

### Windows 7

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

### Windows XP

```
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

### Linux

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/
```

**Note:** Additional directories are created when you have multiple profiles in Chrome. To get to an extension installed for the second profile, replace `/Default` with `/Profile 1`.

Comment: There are no crx files in Windows 7 at C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions , only folders.

Comment: but this folder has folders with such names as "chlffgpmiacpedhhbkiomidkjlcfhogd" how to identify which one corresponds to which one?

Comment: @KNU Go to `chrome://extensions/` and select Developer Mode. Then you can see the ID for each of your extensions.

Comment: @JDavis great. thankx. could I copy it and paste to another machine. and expect it to work there? "Clearly" an app by evernote which was discontinued recently. I intend to preserve it and use on my other machines.

Comment: On Mac my path was: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/PROFILE X/Extensions`

Answer (score 3):

On Windows that's:

```
%Chrome Install Path%\User Data\Default\Extensions\%ID%
```

I suppose it's something similar on Mac.