# Is there any way to get <embed> tag resources in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get a pdf embedded in a html document. https://pdfobject.com/static.html this is the reference site.

A pdf document is embedded using `<embed>` tag on `HTML` page

I have following things-

1. If I open the chrome browser (I'm using `Version 55.0.2883.87 m` ) and do inspect element on that `<embed>` tag or do click `F12` and then inspect the same it shows the tag contents as -

   ```
   <embed src="chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/content/web/viewer.html?file=https%3A%2F%2Fpdfobject.com%2Fpdf%2Fsample-3pp.pdf#page=2" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%">
   ```
2. But if I use following script to get the `embed` tag html

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");
   driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.get("https://pdfobject.com/static.html");
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   driver.switchTo().frame(1);     
   String tagdata = driver.findElement(By.id("plugin")).getAttribute("outerHTML");     
   System.out.println(tagdata);
   ```

   It retrieve result as -

   ```
   <embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=2" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="9">
   ```

but in `chrome` opened by `chromedriver.exe` If i do `F12` and inspect the embed it shows same as above result but if i do right click on that `embed` tag and then click `inspect element`, It opens new developer tool console where I see `<embed>` tag as -

```
<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=2" stream-url="blob:chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/e8337a7a-5af1-456c-8f7a-d8132c67fe6d" headers="Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Content-Length: 49672
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Wed, 25 Jan 2017 04:51:36 GMT
Expires: Fri, 24 Feb 2017 04:51:36 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 19 Mar 2016 06:18:44 GMT
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Server: Apache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
" background-color="0xFF525659" top-toolbar-height="56" top-level-url="https://pdfobject.com/static.html">
```

Snaps for the same is -

[image]

I have some few questions here -

1. variation to do inspect element using system installed `chrome` and `chromedriver.exe` opened `chrome` ?
2. Is there any way to get the  result as opened by chromedriver ?
3. Is there any way to get `embedded` html ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the [PDF Viewer Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm) installed which does the PDF renderring if you run Chrome manually. If Chrome is started by chromedriver however, it runs without any browser extensions, which is why in that case you get the default behavior of Chrome (which is to render the PDF by itself).

If you actually need to verify that the PDF is loaded and rendered with that particular extension, then you can use the following method to load the extension also when Chrome is started by chromedriver (code taken from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions)):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

See here on how to get the crx file of your extension: [Location of CRX in chrome after installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134420/location-of-crx-in-chrome-after-installation)

Comment: Thanks for reply. You are right ` PDF Viewer Chrome extension` was installed in my system . after disabling it showing same `behavior` as opened chrome by `chromedriver`. Do I get the default rendered content of `<embed>` tag as I expecting. comes in newly opened developer tool console ?